# Retrieve xsl:variable in xml using PHP

Tags: php, xml

Note.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./xsl/avsdk.xsl"?>

<Table CreatedOn="Tue Nov 17 22:30:53 PST 2015" Name="Hello" Version="3.6.10294.2" TimeStamp="1447828253">
.....
.....
</Table>
```

Previoulsy we have used the above xml file and used the below PHP command to retrieve the value for Table tag Name and Version, and processed the Table data using Xml object to convert it to other format.

PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml")
$table_attrs = $xml->attributes();
if( 0 === strpos( $table_attrs["Name"], "Hello" ) )
{
.....
}
else if( 0 === strpos( $table_attrs["Name"], "Hai" ) )
{
.....
}
```

Now the XML file format changed like below. So i have changed the command like below(i.e $xml->Table[0]->attributes()) to take the Table tag Name and version, and store the entire table content as a XML object to convert it to other format. when i tried to run the below PHP command, it throws the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on null". Please let me know the command to take Table Name and version, and how to store the entire Table content as a xml object

Note.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="#sc_stylesheet"?>
<!DOCTYPE supportchart [<!ATTLIST xsl:stylesheet id ID #REQUIRED>]>

<xsl:stylesheet id="sc_stylesheet" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="support_chart">
        <supportchart>
            <Table CreatedOn="Wed Feb 03 15:52:32 2016" Name="Hello" Version="4.2.326.0" Timestamp="1454543552.61">
            .....
            .....
            </Table>
        </supportchart>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:template match="Table">
    ....
    ....
    <xsl:template match="xsl:template"> </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

PHP:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml")
$table_attrs = $xml->Table[0]->attributes();
if( 0 === strpos( $table_attrs["Name"], "Hello" ) )
{
.....
}
else if( 0 === strpos( $table_attrs["Name"], "Hai" ) )
{
.....
}
```

Comment: While your first is an XML file, the second is XSLT file. XSLT is a special-purpose declarative language (same type as SQL) to manipulate XML. And it is a fully compliant XML document but usually doesn't hold data. Usually one doesn't parse an .xsl but its end output.

Comment: Do you have access to source XML? Is it the first post? And is above .xsl the same referenced stylesheet in above xml? PHP can process this xslt, then parse needed attributes with transformed output.

Comment: I dont have access to source XML. I just received this XML file from third party vendor. can you please let me know how to parse this Table content from xsl:varaible XSLT file.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, XSLT is a well-formed XML document that most parsers should handle but usually one would not parse a script file for data (*akin to parsing a PHP script for MySQL data*). But since actual values are used in variable definition of XSLT, consider using [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) and then use its `xpath()` method to parse your needed attributes. In XPath queries, attributes require `@` in its referencing but not needed for node values:

```
$data = file_get_contents("$note.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($data);

$nameArray = $xml->xpath("//Table/@Name");
$versionArray = $xml->xpath("//Table/@Version");
$timestampArray = $xml->xpath("//Table/@Timestamp");
```

Should you need to parse node or attribute values enclosed in a namespace prefix, here being `xsl`, you will need to register the `xsl` namespace first:

```
$data = file_get_contents("$note.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($data);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('xsl', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform');

$variableArray = $xml->xpath("//xsl:variable/@name");
```